# Display records and child records from the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have got a table in mysql whose data is as follows

```
code    itemcode    qty    subcode    
1       "A"         1      0  
2       "B"         2      0  
3       "C"         3      1  
4       "D"         4      1
```

I would like to display these records as given below.

```
code   itemcode  qty  subcode  
1      "A"       1    0  
3      "C"       3    1  
4      "D"       4    1  
2      "B"       2    0
```

The records which belong to the same group will have the same subcode. I would like to display all the records sorted by their code and below each instance of the code I would like to display records which have the same value in the subcode field. Can anybody help me.

Comment: The post's question/title doesn't seem very clear. Based on your data and expected output, it's a mere sorting by the `qty` field. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bad design to do this kind of sorting in the query itself. At the client side, you'll probably do some rearranging anyway to show the relation, so I would do two queries:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE subcode=0 -> gives all top elements

SELECT * FROM table WHERE subcode!=0 ORDER BY subcode -> gives all sub elements grouped per parent node.

Then in your client code you can easily rebuild the relationship in an object model and  then display it any way you need.

If you really need it in a query, Oracle has some direct support for it:
SELECT * FROM table CONNECT BY PRIOR subcode=code. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm#i2060615.

In MySQL, you'd have to resort to recursive stored procedures as described in e.g: http://evolt.org/node/4047/.

Comment: This query is for a report which is going to be displayed in a dbgrid which will be linked to a data access control in delphi. So I thought it would be better if all the display logic is done at mysql level in the stored procedure.

Comment: I know that oracle has got it but I am using mysql as my database server.